# Find the PDF of $y=e^x$ where x is standard normal distributed

Tags: probability, statistics

> Find the PDF of $y=e^x$ where x is standard normal distributed

How should I approach this problem? Don't I need limits to solve for $y$$=e^x$?

Comment: $Y\sim$ Log-normal distribution.

Comment: This is the lognormal distribution. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $Y = g(X)$ for some monotone function $g$, then the PDF of $Y$ is given by $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy}\right|.$$

Comment: Do you have a link to somewhere that shows this identity in more detail? I'm curious about the derivation.

Comment: This is Theorem 2.1.5 in Casella and Berger.  A derivation is not difficult; it essentially involves expressing the CDF of $Y$ in terms of the CDF of $X$, then using the chain rule to obtain the PDF.

Comment: Ah, doh, I forgot the chain rule is a thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $Y= f(X)$, then $X = f^{-1}(Y)$, so compute it. What would be P$(Y< y)$? so you'll get something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{f^{-1}(y)}{2}}\bigg|\frac{d f^{-1}(y)}{dy}\bigg| $